# R ggpubr: add mean horizontal line & pair comparisons by group?

Tags: r, statistics, comparison, boxplot

I recently discovered great `ggpubr` package. As I work with multiple groups, I like split my data in facets (`facet.by`).

My question is composed by two subquestions, related to the same graph. I would like to

1. **add unique mean horizontal line per group**, and
2. **plot only significant comparisons by group**

My goal is to display boxplots together with their pair comparison significance values. As significance can be different by groups, I can plots only significant groups, or specify the significant comparisons, and plots them individually per group.

Example data:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)  

# Create data
# :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

# Create basic plot
p <- ggboxplot(df, 
               x = "dose", 
               y = "len",
               color = "dose", 
               palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
               add = "jitter",
               facet.by = "supp", # define faceting 
               shape = "dose")

# Add horizontal line per each group???
p + geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$len), #aggregate(len ~ supp, df, mean)$len, # mean(df$len), 
               linetype = 2,
               group = "supp")
```

Leads to

[image].

I tried to calculate means per group (`#aggregate(len ~ supp, df, mean)$len`), but it just added two lines.

---

To specify paired boxplots to show significance results, I can add

```
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )
```

Significance results are group-dependent. Yet, I want to show only the significant comparisons. How can I specify only significant pairs per group? Something like:

```
my_comp_OJ <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("0.5", "2"))
my_comp_VC <- list(  c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2"))
```

Applying `hide.ns = TRUE` hide only `ns`, but keeps line indication of pairs.

```
p +  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons,
                        label = "p.signif",
                        hide.ns = TRUE) +   # Add pairwise comparisons p-value 
    stat_compare_means(label.y = 50)        # Add global p-value
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to calculate the grand mean for each group and have a data.frame which denotes from which group which mean comes from.

```
> aggregate(len ~ supp, data = df, FUN = mean)
  supp      len
1   OJ 20.66333
2   VC 16.96333
```

It is trivial to include this in `geom_hline`.

```
grand.means <- aggregate(len ~ supp, data = df, FUN = mean)
ggboxplot(df, 
          x = "dose", 
          y = "len",
          color = "dose", 
          palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
          add = "jitter",
          facet.by = "supp", # define faceting 
          shape = "dose") +
  geom_hline(data = grand.means, aes(yintercept = len),
             linetype = 2,
             group = "supp")
```

Notice that there is a `data` argument and I man `len` to `yintercept` within `aes` call. This makes `ggplot` aware that it correctly applies `aes` variables to corresponding groups, no matter how you're applying them.

[image]

As for the tweaked significance bars, I don't think there's a ready answer because `ggpubr` calls `ggsignif` which does have a `manual` parameter but former doesn't implement it, at least as far as I can see upon skimming the source code. I think having the line there is fine, because it shows a comparison was made, even if it's non-significant.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! I did not know that I can so easily define data source  in geom_hline, but it definitely makes sense !